# error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected for .map() operator

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Tried few solutions from different sites but does not help.
issue is : trying to run my app but getting below error:

---

> 10% building modules 0/1 modules 1 active …\src\app\contacts\contacts.component.tsERROR in src/app/contact.service.ts(18,7): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
>   src/app/contact.service.ts(27,7): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
>   src/app/contact.service.ts(33,7): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

---

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Headers, Response} from '@angular/http';
    import { Contact } from './contact';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

            @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ContactService {

        constructor(private http: Http) { }

        // Retrieving contacts
        getContacts() {
          return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/contacts');
          .map((res: any) => res.json());

        }

        // Adding contacts
        addContact(newContact) {
          var headers = new Headers;
          headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/contact', newContact, {headers: headers});
          .map((res: Response) => res.json());
        }

        // Delete contact method
        deleteContact(id) {
          return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/contact' + id);
          .map((res: Response) => res.json());
        }
    }
```

line `.map((res: any) => res.json());` says :

> declaration or statement expected.

Comment: Why do you have `;` before the `.map` ? It should be `return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/contacts').map((res: any) => res.json());`

Comment: I think `.map()` was meant to be `.then()` (?)

Comment: @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir : Removing ';' resolved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You clearly have `;` before the `.map`. It should be

```
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/contacts')
     .map((res: any) => res.json());
```

as this cause end of statement and `.map` will have a syntax error

Comment: yes ';' (semicolon)  was the problem. removing ';'  resolves my issue. Thanks for help.